# Android custom tab layouts

Tags: android, layout, tabs

How I can add custom layout for tabs? For example I want add icons and titles in tabs. And custom active/inactive colors. Code:

```
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);
    TabSpec tab1spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1");
    TabSpec tab2spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2");
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab1spec, ConverterFragment.class, savedInstanceState);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab2spec, RatesFragment.class, savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
```

Comment: http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YourClass.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_options_home))
                  .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

With the preceding code you should be able to create the tabs, associate an intent in order to start an activity and set an icon for the tabs (5th line, **"Home"** will be the title of the tab). That icon will change depending on if the tab is active or inactive, but for that you need to define a file "tab_options_home.xml" (or whatever name you want, but remember to change it in the code) and save it into the `drawable` folder. The file should look like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Icon used when selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_icon"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- Icon used when not selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/regular_icon" />
```

With this xml you define which icon should be used when the tab is active (`state_selected="true"`) or inactive. I know is too late but hope it helps anyone who needs it

PS: remember to extend `TabActivity`